# How can I add a Node to a List using Physics.Raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how are you? I'm trying to make a system of nodes and their neighbors using Raycast.

The problem I'm getting is that I can't add those Nodes to the list, I attach the Script I'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Node : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sphereRadius;

    [SerializeField] List<Node> _neighborsNodes = new List<Node>();
    [SerializeField] LayerMask _nodeMask;

    RaycastHit _hitRigth;
    RaycastHit _hitLeft;
    RaycastHit _hitUp;
    RaycastHit _hitDown;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, out _hitRigth, _nodeMask))
        {
            Debug.Log(_hitRigth.transform.name);

            if (_hitRigth.collider.tag == "Node")
                _neighborsNodes.Add(_hitRigth.collider.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (_neighborsNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs on line 24, where it says `_neighborsNodes.Add(_hitRigth.collider.gameObject);`. The problem here is "Argument 'number' cannot convert from UnityEngine.GameObject to Node". What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Often, reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error is pretty simple you list

```
[SerializeField] List<Node> _neighborsNodes = new List<Node>();
```

is supposed to hold items of type `Node`.

You are trying to add a `GameObject`

```
_neighborsNodes.Add(_hitRigth.collider.gameObject);
```

you rather want to get the according component and do

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, out var hitRigth, _nodeMask))
    {
        Debug.Log(_hitRigth.transform.name);

        if (hitRigth.collider.TryGetComponent<Node>(out var node))
        {
            _neighborsNodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

**HOWEVER**, this is called each and every frame! So you might still end up with hundreds of duplicate items in the list with the very same `node` reference!

=> You should probably rather use a `HashSet`

```
private readonly HashSet<Node> _neighborsNodes = new List<Node>();

private void Update()
{
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, out var hitRigth, _nodeMask))
    {
        Debug.Log(_hitRigth.transform.name);

        if (hitRigth.collider.TryGetComponent<Node>(out var node))
        {
            _neighborsNodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

a `HashSet` ensures every item is only contained exactly **once**.